# Question in Introductory Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I really need help with this question. I am in an introductory linear algebra course. If you guys could help me, I would really appreciate it. Here is the question:

> A large apartment building is to be built using modular construction
>   techniques. The arrangement of apartments on any particular floor is
>   to be chosen from one of the three basic floor plans.
>
> - Each floor of
>     plan A includes: 3 three bedroom units, 7 two bedroom units and 8 one
>     bedroom unit.
> - Each floor of plan B includes 4 three bedroom units, 4
>     two bedroom units and 8 one bedroom units.
> - Each floor of plan C
>     includes: 5 three bedroom units 3 two bedroom units and 9 one bedroom
>     units.
>
> Suppose the building contains a total of $x_1$ floors of plan A,
>   $x_2$ floors of plan B, and $x_3$ floors of plan C.
>
> Is it possible to design
>   the building with exactly 66 three bedroom units, 14 two bedroom units
>   and 136 one bedroom units?
>
> If it can be done, list two different ways
>   to design the building and if not, explain why.

Comment: Perhaps it is only me, but I didn't even try to read through that: it looks pretty unappealing. Try to make things look better, more spacing, lines, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Think about this in the context of a system of linear equations..

Plan A = (3,7,8)
Plan B = (4,4,8)
Plan C = (5,3,9)
Total = (66,14,136)

\begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 4 & 5 & 66 \\
    7 & 4 & 3 & 14 \\
    8 & 8 & 9 & 136 \\
  \end{bmatrix}

Is this system consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You could model plan $A$ using the vector $a = (3,7,8)^T$, where $T$ means matrix transposition, so I use column vectors here.

How can you write your design condition using such vectors?

Answer (score 0):

In all three floor plans the greatest the ration of three bedrooms : two bedrooms is 5:3

but the spec is greater than 4:1.

There is no way to do it unless you can build negative floors on some plan.